# Show Unwanted Post in Single Page From Left Sidebar Popular Posts

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

When I make the layout with left sidebar, then my single page doesn't work properly. It means, single page query post from left sidebar last post of popular widget.

You can check the screenshot below 
[image]

My class:

```
class banyansopno_show_popular extends WP_Widget {

    function banyansopno_show_popular() {
         $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'banyansopno_show_popular', 'description' => esc_html__('Show your popular posts.', 'banyansopno'));
         parent::__construct('banyansopno_show_popular', esc_html__('- @ Banyan Popular Posts @ -', 'banyansopno'), $widget_ops);
     }

    function widget($args, $instance){
        extract($args);


         $title = $instance['title'];
         $postscount = $instance['posts'];

        //GET the posts
        $popularpost = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => $postscount,'meta_key' => 'wpb_post_views_count', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC','post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ) ) );

        echo '<h3 class="widget-title">'.$title.'</h3>' ;

        //SHOW the posts

            while ( $popularpost->have_posts() ) : $popularpost->the_post();

            ?>              
            <div class="widget widget_latest_posts_entries">                  
                <ul>
                    <li>
                      <div class="featured-image">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>         
                      </div>
                      <div class="post-content">
                        <p class="post-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
                        <span class="category">
                            <?php if( esc_attr(get_theme_mod( 'show_categories', 1 ) ) ) {
                                banyansopno_categories_list();
                            } ?>
                        </span>
                        <span class="post-date"><?php the_date('F j, Y'); ?> at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?></span>
                      </div>
                    </li>                    
               </ul>
            </div>
            <?php

            endwhile;

     }

        function update($newInstance, $oldInstance){
             $instance = $oldInstance;
             $instance['title'] = strip_tags($newInstance['title']);
             $instance['posts'] = $newInstance['posts'];

             return $instance;
         }

        function form($instance){

            $title = isset($instance['title'])? $instance['title'] : 'Popular Post\'s';
            echo '<p style="text-align:right;"><label  for="'.$this->get_field_id('title').'">' . esc_html__('Title:', 'banyansopno') . '  <input style="width: 200px;" id="'.$this->get_field_id('title').'"  name="'.$this->get_field_name('title').'" type="text"  value="'.esc_attr($title).'" /></label></p>';

            $posts = isset($instance['posts'])? $instance['posts'] : '3';
            echo '<p style="text-align:right;"><label  for="'.$this->get_field_id('posts').'">' . esc_html__('Number of Posts:', 'banyansopno') . ' <input style="width: 50px;"  id="'.$this->get_field_id('posts').'"  name="'.$this->get_field_name('posts').'" type="text"  value="'.esc_attr($posts).'" /></label></p>';

            echo '<input type="hidden" id="custom_recent" name="custom_recent" value="1" />';
         }
    }    
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("banyansopno_show_popular");'));
```

Can you help me solve this issue?

Comment: what exactly is not displaying right? it is not clear...

Comment: When i click a post link,it's don't show in single page but show last post of popular widget from left sidebar.Please check screenshot and click another post link.

Comment: Please click another post link , you may see same post show in single page and this post come from left sidebar popular post widget.